# SearchPoints -> Automatic within DifferentialEvolution: what's its meaning?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, options

A simple question: what is the meaning of the standard option (`Automatic`) for `SearchPoints` within the `DifferentialEvolution` method?

I see in the Mathematica help that `SearchPoints -> Automatic` has different meanings depending on the method for global optimization, say for `RandomSearch` it is "min(10 d,100), where d is the number of variables". For `SimulatedAnnealing` it is min(2 d,50). And for `DifferentialEvolution`? The same help page (whose title is ["Numerical Nonlinear Global Optimization"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html) does not explain this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Trace` we find that default value of the suboption `"SearchPoints"` is `Min[10 d, 50]`:

```
Trace[NMinimize[{y + x + (1 - x)^2, x^2 + y^2 <= 1}, {x, y}, 
  Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution"}], 
 _[Optimization`NMinimizeDump`searchpoints, _], TraceInternal -> True]
```

> `` {{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{Optimization`NMinimizeDump`searchpoints = 
>                           If[Optimization`NMinimizeDump`initpts === 
>                           Automatic, 
>                           Min[10 Optimization`NMinimizeDump`dim, 50], 
>                           Max[Min[10 Optimization`NMinimizeDump`dim, 50], 
>                           Length[Optimization`NMinimizeDump`initpts]]], 
>                           Optimization`NMinimizeDump`searchpoints = 
>                           20}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}} ``

The variable name  `` Optimization`NMinimizeDump`searchpoints `` is found by searching for  the term `"SearchPoints"` in the huge output from

```
Trace[NMinimize[{y + x + (1 - x)^2, x^2 + y^2 <= 1}, {x, y}, 
  Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution"}], TraceInternal -> True]`.
```

Answer (score 1):

Option processing may also be inspected in `optionCheck[]`:

```
Needs@"GeneralUtilities`";
PrintDefinitions@Optimization`NMinimizeDump`optionCheck

Optimization`NMinimizeDump`optionCheck[
 NMinimize`DifferentialEvolution, caller_, l,_] :=
  ...
  If[SameQ[searchpoints, Automatic],
        searchpoints = If[
                SameQ[initpts, Automatic],
                Min[10 * dim, 50],
                Max[Min[10 * dim, 50], Length @ initpts]
            ]
    ];
  ...
```